# Cannot focus a child element using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bxslider

I'm using [bxSlider](http://bxslider.com/), but I cannot focus a child element of my `<ul>` list.  I want to focus a `<div>` or `<li>` within it. Below is a part of my **HTML** code:

```
<div class="bx-wrapper" style="max-width: 1308px; margin: 0px auto;">
<div class="bx-viewport" style="width: 100%; overflow: hidden; position: relative; height: 58px;">
    <ul id="jalur" class="jalur" tabindex="21" style="width: 2715%; position: relative; transition-duration: 0s; transform: translate3d(-40px, 0px, 0px);">
        <li id="lix1" style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 218px;">
            <div class="fl">
                <div id="e1" class="fl kurohige-prev jaman" data-time="00:30">00:30-01:00</div>
                <div class="fl line-0"></div>
            </div>
        </li>
        <li id="lix2" style="float: left; list-style: outside none none; position: relative; width: 218px;">

        ...
    </ul>   
</div>
```

I've tried to focus on the child `<div>`with id 'e1', but failed. Below is the related JavaScript code:

```
    $(document).on( "keydown", function(event) {
    var key = event.which;
    console.log(key); //39-->right 37-->left, 38-->up 40-->down
    if (key == '39') //success
    {
        var foc = $(':focus');
        $(foc).next().focus();
        console.log(foc);
    }
    else if (key == '37') //success
    {
        var foc = $(':focus');
        $(foc).prev().focus();
        console.log(foc);
    }
    else if (key == '40') //failed
    {
        $('#jalur li').first().focus();
        var foc = $(':focus');
        console.log(foc);
    }
    else if (key == '38') //failed
    {
        $('#jalur').children(":first").focus();
        var foc = $(':focus');
        console.log(foc);
    }
});
```

However, using Firebug's command line I can go to any element:

```
$('#jalur li').first().focus();
```

This will give the following output:

```
Object[li#lix1]
```

I want to to get `data-time="00:30"` from the `<div>` and also focus it.

Comment: focus wont work on `li` .This event is implicitly applicable to a limited set of elements, such as form elements (<input>, <select>, etc.) and links (<a href>).

Comment: It could be from coping and pasting code incorrectly. But this code has errors. Speisically you cannot have the `else if (key == '40')`, it needs to be an `if (key == '40')` and you a missing a `)` at the end.

Comment: Thanks for comment, edited...

Answer (score 1):

Focus won't work on `<li>` .

From jQuery Docs,

> This event is implicitly applicable to a limited set of elements, such
>   as form elements (`<input>`, `<select>`, etc.) and links (`<a href>`).

Also I don't know what you want to achieve but,

You can do,

```
$('#jalur li').first().effect('highlight', {}, 1000);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Dipak1991/c82qf5tz/)**